# Can any C++ 98 standard container operations throw std::bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, stl

I was trying to work out if the try catch is needed in the following code:

```
std::vector<int> values;
// ignore that this can throw std::bad_alloc
values.push_back(1);
try {
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = values.begin();
         iter != values.end(); ++iter) {
         ++(*iter);
    }
} catch (const std::bad_alloc&) { 
    // Is this needed?
}
```

Looking through the C++ 1998 standard the only thing I can find which hints at this is section 23.1 "Container requirements" bullet point 8 which contains the sentence:

> A copy of this argument is used for any memory allocation performed, by these constructors and by all member functions, during the lifetime of each container object.

My interpretation of this is that any member function in a container can call the allocator so any member function can throw std::bad_alloc. Am I being overly paranoid or is this really the case?

Comment: Are you looking at the 98 standard because of a compiler-restriction? Because there's 03 and now 11.

Comment: @GManNickG - yes, it's due to limitations in the supported compiler for the platform I'm targeting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you carry on reading a bit further, you'll find 23.1/10, which gives the containers' requirements regarding when exceptions can be thrown, in particular:

- no `erase()`, `pop_back()` or `pop_front()` function throws an exception.
- no copy constructor or assignment operator of a returned iterator throws an exception.

If you're truly paranoid, then you should consider the possiblity of `begin()` and `end()`, and even iterator increment, throwing; but there's no need for them to do anything complicated in any sane implementation of the standard containers.

Answer (score 2):

Theorotically Yes, any standard library container member function can throw `bad_alloc`.

Most standard Containers themselves do not throw any exceptions except (`std::vector::at()`) but they can throw exceptions for memory allocation failures or exceptions of user-defined operations.

I assume your fear is that `push_back()` throws in your example case, if not then yes you are being paranoid. Eventhough, it is an implementation detail In practice almost none of the implemenatations will try to allocate if you are just getting iterators(`begin()`, `end()`).

Comment: I'm happy that the 'push_back()' can throw, I would expect that for any sane implementation of a container. I was wondering what other container method calls could throw and it appears that the majority of them, including accessing entries, could throw.

Comment: @FreeWildebeest: Technically, Yes. Practically No.

Comment: I did once `container.resize(var1 * var2)` where `var2` was uninitialised (and large). The result was a bad_alloc

Comment: @Michael: `var2` being uninitialized, Your program already had an UB so technically, anything could happen really.

Comment: @Als - but how can I be sure that a closed source implementation that I'm using won't throw bad_alloc from one of the methods?

Comment: @FreeWildebeest: That is what I indicated, *You cannot* but then being that paranoid I don't think you can write too much code really.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find something more specific in the standard, so in the absence of evidence we 'll have to conclude that technically any container method can throw `bad_alloc`.

I wouldn't worry about `begin` and `end` throwing as far as the container itself is concerned, but there's another troubling point: iterator implementation. If iterators are of class type then theoretically the construction (or assignment) of such instances could very well throw. So while I don't think it's probable that any randomly chosen standard library implementation would throw, you can't really rule it out.